# php xdebug not work

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm a newbie in php, when i step into php,I want to debug php script.
I use homebrew to install xdebug with version xdebug.

as the config file shows,I think it is right.
I use php build in server.

```
php -S localhost:2001
```

I use phpstorm 10 and set break point.and the **Validate Debugger Configuration** is pass.
[image]
and then I start listen the debug connection and run debug php.
but it's does not work.

Comment: I can not post my screenshot about php --ini php -v xdebug.ini as SO said the code was not formated......  
the php version is 5.1.6 ,xdebug version is 2.3.3
the xdebug ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php56-xdebug/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1

Comment: use CTRL+K to format your source code :)

Comment: I know as it ask me to CTRL+K to format,but it is a screenshot , it 's a picture. so I can not format it ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at last , I solved my problem.
I think everything I have config is right.
the php.ini,the xdebug.ini.
the problem is port,xdebug default port is 9000,
I checked my dev machine port,9000 is listen by php-fpm,
may be that is why I can't listen port 9000 with php-storm.
I **changed xdebug.ini default port to 9001**,everything is well.

if someone has config well,but can not debug with ide.
please check is the port is be used.
the doc shows 
[how the debug communication is set up](http://xdebug.org/docs/all#communication)

Answer (score 1):

1.use phpinfo() to see if xdebug is enabled.
2.I use chrome as a client,install xdebug helper
3.enable the button on chrome.(make it green)
4.this is what you have done with phpstorm
5.accept your local web by Chrome.
These are my steps,hoping helpful.